# let pos = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + document.documentElement.offsetHeight;

Tags: angular, scroll-position

this line doesn't show me the exact position of the scroller in the first time it shows 687 as the position in the second click it shows the same location as 617 it doesn't change after the second click.

Comment: can you share the complete code which you have written so far on stackblitz.com It will help future readers to get more context and help you solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onScroll(event: any) 
    {
        //visible height + pixel scrolled = total height 
        if (event.target.offsetHeight + event.target.scrollTop == event.target.scrollHeight) 
        {
                 this.buttonDisabled=false;

```
    }
    else
    {
             this.buttonDisabled=true;

    }
}
```